# Sending bulkmail from different server?

Tags: vps, mx-record, email-server

I want to send bulk domains from my vps for a domain(cagetur.com) hosted in another company. The company(cagetur) will go on using the old hosting account for its mailing operations.

The vps will just be used for smtp for once a week. I created an A record "vps.cagetur.com". directed it to the IP adress of vps then created a mx record with bigger preference number "50 vps.cagetur.com." on the domain control panel. When I trace the "vps.cagetur.com" i can reach my vps now.

I installed hMail on the vps. Configure it (created domain, accounts). I have no information about "system" so i couldn't get further from this point. I can connect to the mail server with Outlook without errors. I can send an email from the account on the vps but it doesn't reaches. No errors, no emails.

What do i have to do for getting it work? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure your VPS provider allows outgoing email?

Comment: Yes it does. Is there anything i have to check on the VPS because it's an unmanaged VPS. For example it does not have DNS Server installed. I  have no information on system side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume that:

1. This is a company needing to send out email marketing blasts to customers.
2. You want these emails to actually be received by those customers.

Do yourself a huge favor and don't use your vps to send those emails... Your deliverability numbers will be horrible. Why? Because your vps could be sharing an IP address or range with hundreds of spammers and you wouldnt know it (unless you check your IP on some real time blacklists ... Google "RBL CHECK")

For marketing blasts, I'd seriously consider paying for an smtp relay service such as socketlabs or sendgrid who specializes in maintaining high deliverability rates... You'll be glad you did.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm a working in the ISP that I leased the IP from. The IP block is clean. The mass mailing companies are requesting too much money to do mailing with my data.

I'm still waiting for configuration suggestions, thank you.

Comment: Absolutely. From my experience, and I'm not trying to sell their services, not only does sendgrid get good results, but you can't underestimate how much they know about spamming^Wbulk E-mail and will guide you in your DNS configuration. The work involved to please all major E-mail providers is also quite significant. I assume all serious bulk E-mail services will similarly get a lot out of your plate.

Comment: @Omer  OK, so you have a clean IP... that's an excellent first step. but there are a ton of others...  for example, joining the feedback loops (FBL) for all the major ISPs (gmail, yahoo, hotmail etc.).  If a GMail customer marks your email as spam.... and you keep sending that customer emails, Google will eventually punish you by sending your emails straight to the spam folders of its clients. An email service provider (ESP) will handle all of that for you and protect you from yourself in a dozen different ways.

Comment: My customer can't afford ESP's. Thats why we try to use the vps. This is the only solution for now. Thanks anyway for your help.